# Is there any simulation program for electrostatic and magnetostatic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, simulations, software

please can any one suggest me a good program for simulating electrostatic and magnetostatic fields (forces,flux density, energy and potential) ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a software request and not physics.

Comment: There are hundreds and this is not a physics question.

Comment: How much money are you willing to spend... Comsol multiphysics springs to mind.